# Highcharts - label options UI suddenly appear

Tags: highcharts

When I interact with a chart on a mobile device (zooming, panning, tapping) suddenly an unwanted label options UI appear (see screenshot link below). This is rendered in the highcharts canvas and is not something I have added or configured.

Anyone knows what this is and how to get rid of it?

Unfortunately I don't have exact repro steps how to reproduce this, it doesn't happen often.
It's happened both on iOS Safari and Android Chrome.
It's a web implementation using HighchartsReact.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CKMy.png)

Comment: Could you provide more information? Are you using the react-native highcharts wrapper or highcharts-android?

Comment: Thanks @SebastianWędzel for your reply. I've added information in the description.

Comment: Are you able to share a config of your chart? (JSON). If you don't want to share it in public you can send it to my email: sebastian.wedzel@blacklabel.pl Some sample data will be very useful. We will try to reproduce it and debug on our devices.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, I've sent you an email with the config. I don't expect you to be able to easily reproduce the issue, I was more wondering if anyone had seen it before.

Comment: I got your email, thank you. We will respond in 24 hours. In meanwhile, could you share steps how to reproduce and see this issue?

Comment: Hi @OlofLandahl, the current wrapper (like other wrappers) does not support Highstock yet. Unforutnately as I see you use it, as a result it can work incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

I think `xAxis.minorTickInterval` property should work for you, if it doesn't check out other tick properties on API.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minorTickInterval

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Why should minorTickInterval help?